# How to Configure Rollup to Transpile Code Based on the Target Environment?

Tags: javascript, rollup

I have a piece of JavaScript code that includes environment-specific logic and I'm using Rollup to bundle and transpile my code. I want to configure Rollup to produce different outputs based on whether the target environment is Node.js or a browser.

Here's an example of the code in my source file (`index.js`):

```js
const self = typeof window === 'undefined' ? global : window;
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  console.log('is browser');
} else {
  console.log('is node', existsSync('index.js'));
}
```

When targeting Node.js, I want the output to be:

```js
const self = global;
console.log('is node', existsSync('index.js'));
```

For browsers, the code should be transpiled but retain the browser-specific logic.

I'm currently using Rollup to bundle my code, and my existing configuration looks like this:

```js
// rollup.config.js
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('@rollup/plugin-commonjs');
const babel = require('@rollup/plugin-babel');
const { rollup } = require('rollup');

const basePlugins = [
  commonjs(),
  babel({
    babelHelpers: 'bundled'
  }),
];

async function build(isServe = false) {
  // ... (existing configuration)
}

module.exports = build;
```

How can I modify my existing Rollup configuration to achieve this environment-specific transpilation behavior? Should I create separate configuration files for Node.js and browser targets, and how can I structure my build process accordingly?

Comment: Why would you do this, instead of leaving it a runtime decision?